# onLoadFinished() behavior on screen orientation change

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, asynctaskloader

I have the following `Loader` implemented, which is a subclass of `AsyncTaskLoader`. The `LoaderManager` `initLoaderManager`() is called in the Activity's `onCreate`() method.

When I rotate my screen, I see that the `onLoadFinished`() is getting called successfully, however I don't see any `Loader` lifecycle method (`onStopLoading`(), `onStartLoading`(), `onReset`()).

What is trigerring the `onLoadFinished`() method in this case? As per my understanding the `onLoadFinished`() is triggered by the `Loader's` `deliverResult`() method, which would be called after the `loadInBackground`() is done or we could call it in `onStartLoading`() to deliver the cached data to the `Activity`. In this case I don't see any state change happening for the `Loader`.

```
public EarthquakeLoader(Context context, String url) {
    super(context);
    this.mUrl = url;
}

@Override
public List<Earthquake> loadInBackground() {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "loadInBackGround()");
    List<Earthquake> earthquakes = QueryUtils.extractEarthquakes(this.mUrl);
    return earthquakes;
}

@Override
public void onStartLoading() {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onStartLoading()");
    forceLoad();
}

@Override
public void onStopLoading() {
    super.onStopLoading();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onStopLoading()");
}

public void onReset() {
    super.onReset();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onReset()");
}
```